# Why didn't the Third Hokage choose another successor after Minato died?

Tags: anime, naruto, manga

The Third Hokage wanted to retire so he (eventually) chose Minato as his successor and 4th Hokage.
However, not too long after that, Minato died, and the Third came out of retirement.
So, why didn't the Third choose another successor and go back into retirement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There was no one better suited for the job than the 3rd Hokage, [Hiruzen Sarutobi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiruzen_Sarutobi), after his successor, [Minato Namikaze](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Minato_Namikaze) was killed trying to re-seal the 9 Tailed Fox demon, [Kurama](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kurama), within his son Naruto.**

- The 3rd Hokage was considered one of the most powerful shinobi to have ever lived and carried among his list of titles, God of Shinobi (忍の神, Shinobi no Kami). Even at his advanced age, he had few living equals against his skills and his wisdom was legendary.
- Hiruzen Sarutobi had been trained by the legendary First Hokage and later become the teacher of the [Legendary Sannin](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sannin), Tsunade, Jiraiya, and Orochimaru, three of the most famous Leaf Village shinobi ever known.
- Hiruzen Sarutobi was also trying to ensure that Naruto would be able to grow up with his tacit (but unspoken) support while investigating the threat of Orochimaru, who was beginning a new offensive against the Village in the Leaves.
- After Hiruzen Sarutobi's death, he was succeeded by the legendary Sannin and his student, [Lady Tsunade](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsunade) as the Fifth Hokage.

While the cast of Naruto is very large we must consider that no one even wanted the job when Hiruzen Sarutobi died, it had to be forced upon Lady Tsunade.

- Of the Sannin (whose experience and capabilities made them the most qualified), Orochimaru was an enemy, Jiraiya, while powerful, was a much better field agent and investigating the Akatsuki (a future and deadly threat).
- [Kakashi Hatake](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake), the legendary Copy Ninja while considered a genius, was also better suited to field work than leadership roles at his current age. The same could be said for [Might Guy](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Might_Guy). [Asuma Sarutobi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Asuma_Sarutobi) whose martial skills became a great asset to the Leaf had fallen out with his father, the 3rd Hokage and was unavailable at the time.

Comment: @Thaddeus Dude.... YOU READ MANGAS AS WELL?? What is out there that you do not know about fiction ?

Comment: I love manga. I live overseas for a few years and became addicted to it. I was already a science fiction, fantasy and comics fan so manga and anime were just one more thing to add to an already long list of things to read. I was a child in poor health growing up so I read a lot more than most kids my age did. Even after I got better, the habit stuck and I kept reading at the same rate. In the military, you have a lot of time on your hands, so I used it to keep reading. What amazes me is still how many things I haven't had a chance to read yet...

Comment: I hate to be "that guy" but are there any canon sources that support your statement that there wasn't anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that the next possible contestant after 4th's death could have been Danzo Shimura, the leader of the Root, and Hiruzen wanted to avoid that at all costs. He had previously tried to assassinate the the 3rd Hokage to attain the title and had already been a contestant for the 4th with Minato. So it can be that to avoid Danzo's succession to the title, he retained the title of Hokage .

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Can you provide any source for the claim that it was possibly Danzo Shimura who was next in line? Is that hinted at anywhere? Can you provide a source for that? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so it is mentioned anywhere but I got this possibility from the story itself . I am wrong by saying that he contested for it because actually he recommended Orichimaru . But he did try to assassinate the Third and become the hokage , and he does it when Tsunade is injured . So it could be the very reason why third did what he did but then again it's just a possibility .